# Angular/Rails App Loading Blank CSS Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

In the app I just started I'm having trouble getting my CSS stylesheet to load.  I'm used to using the asset pipeline with rails, but I'm trying to use angular for the front end, which has taken everything out of the asset pipeline.

I have the css file in `public/app/styles/style.css` and am referencing it in my `index.html` with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/style.css">
```

I have images linked successfully with `src=app/assets/images/...` and if I look in the sources tab on the developer console the file *does* show up, it just appears to be empty.

Can anyone see where the disconnect is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see with the code, your  tag could use a 'type' attribute, but that wouldn't stop it from working.

The URL in the link is 'app/styles/style.css', I assume your index.html file is in the 'public' folder?

I'd reality check the URL to ensure it's pointing right to the style.css file, and update the  to use the full HTML5 format, which is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/styles/style.css">
```

Comment: Yesssss.  Thank you!